# Align icon and text inside a div

Tags: css, html

How can I center align the content inside each div?
As you see icons and text are centered inside their own frame but not in div as you can see in the below image:

How can I center align individually?

[image: Center Align]

MY CSS

```
#busareas .row .columns {
            width: auto;
            margin: auto;
            background: #fff;
            color: #d22362;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 85%;
    }
```

MY HTML

```
<!-- Business Areas -->
                        <section id="busareas" class="wrapper style3">
                        <h3>Business Areas</h3>
                            <div class="inner">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                        <div class="two columns">
                                            <i class="fa fa-car fa-5x"></i>
                                            <hr />
                                            <p class="text-box">OEM</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="two columns">
                                            <i class="fa fa-cubes fa-5x"></i>
                                            <hr />
                                            <p class="text-box">STILAGES</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="two columns">
                                            <i class="fa fa-database fa-5x"></i>
                                            <hr />
                                            <p class="text-box">TIRES</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="two columns">
                                            <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-5x"></i>
                                            <hr />
                                            <p class="text-box">AFTERMARKET</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="two columns">
                                            <i class="fa fa-glass fa-5x"></i>
                                            <hr />
                                            <p class="text-box">GLASS</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>
```

Comment: Can you provide HTML and CSS markup which will allow us to replicate the problem.

Comment: If you can add a snippet it would be great

Comment: not sure what exactly you are looking for ...check this snippet if it helps http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWEdxm

Comment: @Geeky Thank you, your answer solved my problem!